# List always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm extremely new to ReactJS and I have no idea what I am doing wrong but my City list always comes back undefined. The number list renders just fine. I have been fighting this for the past 3 hours and I am just stumped.

Could someone please help me out?

I used the create-react-app and I have removed the React.StrictMode from the index.js file. Everything I am doing is in the App.js.

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';

console.clear();

//Simple List of numbers
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let numberList = numbers.map((number) =>
  <li key={number}>{number}</li>
);

//we would pull something from a db and pass it to the function
let cities = ['Boise', 'Nampa', 'Meridian', 'Caldwell'];
let Cities = (arrayList) => {
  
  let cities = arrayList.cities;
  console.log(cities);
  let cityList = cities.map((item, index) =>{
    <li key={index}>{item}</li>
  });
  console.log(cityList);
  return(
    <ul>{cityList}</ul>
  );

  /*
  return(
    <ul>
      {
        //You cannot use a forEach it will always return undefined. ReactJS needs a key so we can use the index of the item
        cities.map((item, index) =>{
          <li key={index}>{item}</li>
        })
      }
    </ul>
  );
  */

};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</h2>
        <div>
          <h2>Numbers</h2>
          <ul>{numberList}</ul>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>Cities</h2>
          <Cities cities={cities}/>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have curly brackets, which means this is a function and you need to return something. e.g. `return <li ...`. More likely, you intended the curly brackets to be parentheses.

```
let cityList = cities.map((item, index) =>{
    <li key={index}>{item}</li>
});
```

You want one of these:

```
let cityList = cities.map((item, index) =>{
    return <li key={index}>{item}</li>
});

let cityList = cities.map((item, index) => (
    <li key={index}>{item}</li>
));
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved the issue. Why did the other one work though?

Comment: Because if you have just one statement in an arrow function, you don't need to add curly bracket + return keyword. Ex: `const numberToString = val => \`${val}\`` is equal to `const numberToString = val => { return \`${val}\`; }`